# Dealing with DOM Manipulations in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When I perform DOM manipulation (add new HTML) using jQuery, AngularJS doesn't automatically detect variables in the new HTML and replace them with their values. For example:

```
$scope.showSummary = function($event){

    $($event.currentTarget).html("<div>{{row}}</div>");

};
```

This is a simple example, but after changing the HTML in the element (this function was called by `ng-click`), the output it still `{{row}}` instead of what *row* should mean in the context/scope.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have to inject `$compile` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) and use it so angular knows about the new html.

`$compile('<div>{{row}}</div')($scope).appendTo($event.currentTarget);`

However, it is frowned upon in angular to do DOM manipulation in your controllers.  You want your controllers to handle business and your views to handle the view.

Try a directive to do what you want. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I was trying to do this for almost a day. You saved a LOT of time. Thanks a lot Andy! You are a rockstar!

Comment: Do you have an authoritative reference supporting the claim that DOM manipulations in controllers are frowned upon?  I would be interested in knowing who so frowns and why.

Answer (score 2):

If you use fragments for new elements (e.g. $("<" + "div>").appendTo("body")), using a wrapper like the following for the JQuery prepend/append methods lets you avoid having to change your element-adding code:

```
// run angular-compile command on new content
// (also works for prependTo/appendTo, since they use these methods internally)
var oldPrepend = $.fn.prepend;
$.fn.prepend = function()
{
    var isFragment = arguments[0][0] && arguments[0][0].parentNode && arguments[0][0].parentNode.nodeName == "#document-fragment";
    var result = oldPrepend.apply(this, arguments);
    if (isFragment)
        AngularCompile(arguments[0]);
    return result;
};
var oldAppend = $.fn.append;
$.fn.append = function()
{
    var isFragment = arguments[0][0] && arguments[0][0].parentNode && arguments[0][0].parentNode.nodeName == "#document-fragment";
    var result = oldAppend.apply(this, arguments);
    if (isFragment)
        AngularCompile(arguments[0]);
    return result;
};

function AngularCompile(root)
{
    var injector = angular.element($('[ng-app]')[0]).injector();
    var $compile = injector.get('$compile');
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    var result = $compile(root)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    return result;
}
```