# Use ng-repeat to add/delete DOM element <input>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question in Angularjs, I try to use ng-repeat to add/delete DOM element input and button for user,so they can use button to add or delete input element.

In fact,my code do word for this.

This is html code:

```
<a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="addInputRow()">add input</a>    
<p class="" ng-repeat="item in controlNumberOfInputRows">
 <span>NO.{{$index+1}}</span>
 name:<input name="name" type="text" class="span2" /> 
 phone:<input name="phone" type="text" class="span2" /> 
 ID:<input name="ID" type="text" class="span3" />
 <a class="class" ng-click="deleteThis($index)">X</a>
</p>
```

javascript code:

```
myModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http){

$scope.controlNumberOfInputRows = [];

$scope.addInputRow = function(){

    $scope.controlNumberOfInputRows.push(0);

}

$scope.deleteThis = function(st){
    $scope.controlNumberOfInputRows.splice(st,1);

};
```

But this code have a bug when user deleting the item, Angulayjs only
delete last one.

If i set:

```
$scope.controlNumberOfInputRows = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

It work very well in [0]~[4],user can delete item by index
,but not in [5]~[X](delete last one)

Why?

P.S 
If i set:

```
$scope.controlNumberOfInputRows = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

It work very well in [0]~[4],user can delete item by index

```
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[1] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[2] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[3] X   << delete this
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[4] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[5] X
```

Then we get:

```
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[1] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[2] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[4] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[5] X
```

If We use add input

```
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[1] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[2] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[3] X   
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[4] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[5] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[6] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[7] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[8] X  << delete this
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[9] X
```

Then we get:

```
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[1] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[2] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[3] X   
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[4] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[5] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[6] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[7] X
name[Wells] Phone[123] ID[8] X
```

I think i resolve my problem by acrobatic:

```
    var index = 0;
    $scope.controlNumberOfInputRows = [];
    $scope.addInputRow = function(){
       index ++;
       $scope.controlNumberOfInputRows.push(index);      
    }
```

This do work well,but why? Idon't known...

Comment: It is working for me http://plnkr.co/edit/Wd4cUaLIRxiaCqENo8FR?p=preview

Comment: My friend,Did you mean keying some different data in these input element and use [X]? It just delete last one.Did u use "add input"?

Comment: Can you help us to recreate the issue/provide steps to recreate the issue using the above demo

Comment: Ok my friend,and sorry for not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i resolve my problem by acrobatic

```
    $scope.addInputRow = function(){
       index ++;
       $scope.controlNumberOfInputRows.push(index);      
    }
```

This do word well,but why? Idon't known...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: will do the delete:

```
<a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="addInputRow()">add input</a>    
<p class="" ng-repeat="(key,value) in controlNumberOfInputRows">
 <span>NO.{{value+1}}</span>
 name:<input name="name" type="text" class="span2" /> 
 phone:<input name="phone" type="text" class="span2" /> 
 ID:<input name="ID" type="text" class="span3" />
 <a class="class" ng-click="deleteThis($index)">X</a>
</p>
```

To do this correctly you should use directives see here: [Dealing with DOM Manipulations - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699635/dealing-with-dom-manipulations-angularjs)

Comment: My friend,use (key,value) can delete,but only last one like mine,and this case don't need code $compile,ng-repeat will do it