# How to use ng-bind on html that is inserted with innerHTML inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-compile

I made a custom directive that had two `ng-repeats` inside of it. One `ng-repeat` was nested inside the other one. I got the code to work, and it performs well in chrome but on the iPad and iPhone it is sluggish.

There are 10 sections with 5 rows each and it needs to be very fast when it comes to scrolling and changing the bindings. I think the slowdown comes from all the loops through the bindings but only one array needs to be changed on user input. The rest of the bindings never change after the page loads.

So I am trying to figure out a way to load nested unordered lists while only binding one variable. This is pseudo code for my directive.

```js
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      outerList = '<ul><li>statically generated content that does not change'
      outerList += '<ul><li ng-bind="I only need to bind one thing"><li></ul>'
      outerList += < /ul>'
      elm[0].innerHTML = outerList
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see I am trying to generate the html content, and then insert it with innerHTML. The problem is the `ng-bind` isn't working when I do it this way. I tried to `$compile` it again but that didn't change anything.

Does anyone have a better way? I don't care how hideous the solution is I just really need this part of the app to be super fast. The main thing is I don't want `ng-repeat` unless there is a way to make it do its thing on load and then never loop through anything again.

I would like to do this in the most Angular way possible but I realize I might have to do something that goes completely against Angular philosophy

Comment: You want something that repeating but don't want to use ngRepeat, that's definitely not the "most angular way" ;) but you have your reason, so someone gonna help you out. Before that, can you create fiddle to demonstrate what is working (but slow), and what is not working?

Comment: It's unclear exactly how you want it to operate. Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/AEBzp/) work for you?  If not, can you explain what it's missing?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. I was just about to update it with a link to a fiddle. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for so now there is no need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, I posted it as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with DOM Manipulations - AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699635/dealing-with-dom-manipulations-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to modify your code in order to bind some variable in a directive from a scope outside of it.  I've used `$compile` to ensure that your directive DOM manipulation has its own directives compiled. I've used `replaceWith` to replace the directive element with your compiled DOM:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlMain">
        <div my-directive="bindMe"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlMain',function($scope){
    $scope.bindMe = {id:1,myvar:"test"};
});
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        varToBind: '=myDirective'     
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      outerList = '<ul><li>statically generated content that does not change'
      outerList += '<ul><li ng-bind="varToBind.myvar"><li></ul>'
      outerList += '</ul>';
      outerList = $compile(outerList)(scope);
      elm.replaceWith(outerList);
    }
  }
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/AEBzp/)